# Do we need synchronization on a private static Map object if multiple threads are reading the value of a particular key with a public method?

Tags: java, multithreading

Do we need *synchronization* here on a `private static Map` object if multiple threads are using `getObject` method which is firstly checking the value on `map` with given key and if not found then putting the new object with that key on `map` object.

```
private static Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

public Object getObject(String key){
    Object obj = map.get(key);
    if(obj == null){
        obj = new Object();
        map.put(key, obj);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do only reading.
You put values in the map too and `HashMap` is not designed to work with concurrent threads if at least one of them makes some writing on the map.

All this should be synchronized to avoid race condition between threads :

```
Object obj = map.get(key);
if(obj == null){
    obj = new Object();
    map.put(key, obj);
}
```

Example of race condition :

For a key `"a"` that is not contained in the map, a thread could be paused here:

```
if(obj == null){
```

Another thread could execute the code with the key `"a"` and so put the element in the map as it is not still contained.
When the first thread is resumed, it overwrites the content of the map for the key `"a"`.

Note that if you use a `ConcurrentHashMap`, you could use `putIfAbsent()` that ensures that the action (check + put if not exit) is performed atomically.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have one a question on putIfAbsent(), here we need to pass a newly created object, which is not good, i want to create object only if its missing in map.?

Comment: `map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new Object())`.

Comment: thanks this will help me.

Answer (score 2):

It says it [right there in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification.)

You call `put` if the value is null (or not present), so you are making structural modifications. If you call this method from multiple threads, you need synchronization.